# Переход на ssl, как правильно?

Tags: ssl, opencart2.0

Сайте подключил на ssl но проблема в том что браузер все равно ругается на не защищенность:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на картинке поддомен `m` но основной домен работает нормально вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

c `http` идет `302` на `https` надеюсь не повлияет на seo.

Comment: В консоли ошибок вроде должны быть выведены точные ссылки, которые оказались без https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам хром детально описал характер проблемы:

> Злоумышленники могут видеть изображения, которые видны вам, и изменять
>   их в целях мошенничества

Это значит, у вас на странице имеются картинки, которые передаются не по https.

Comment: проблему решил путем замена `http` на `https` так как в страницы встречались действительно `http`